# Node.js Decoding a Base64 Image and saving it via API

Tags: node.js, api, express, get, base64

I've been trying to get a quick node.js api working, but I'm running into some issues and I was hoping someone could help.

What I'm trying to do: I'm trying to pass a base64 encoded image data URI to my node.js and have it save the file to my server. I believe that I've almost got it working, but for some reason the image is getting corrupted. When I attempt to run the script when I just hardcode the dataURI in, the saved image is perfect. However, when I use the GET request, the saved file is corrupted and I cannot open it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => { console.log
('Running on port 3000...');
});

app.get('/api/users', function(req, res) {
let base64String = req.param('datauri');
let base64Image = base64String.split(';base64,').pop();

fs.writeFile('image.png', base64Image, {encoding: 'base64'}, function(err) {
console.log('File created');
});
res.send(base64Image);  
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Upon further inspection, it appears that the issue is because the " " (space) are being replaced with "+". Any idea how to resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to url decode the base64 string to replace the special characters back to their original form. I.E. swap `+` back to a space

You should be able to use `decodeURIComponent()`

```
var base_64 = decodeURIComponent(base_64_string);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I gave that a try and while the image does now open, there's quite a bit of artifacting and corruption. I also tried just replacing the spaces with + and received the same issue. Any other ideas that might be worth trying? Thanks in advance!